# Microstuttering (mouse/keyboard) after upgrading to 21.10

Tags: usb, keyboard, mouse, wayland

Recently, I upgraded my Ubuntu 21.04 to 21.10.

Since then, I sometimes experience micro stuttering for both mouse and keyboard - sometimes the cursor lags for a fraction of a second, or a typed symbol appears with a little delay.

Dmesg is full of messages like these:

```
[43100.097065] usb 1-5: restoring control 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000101/10/5
[43100.097069] usb 1-5: restoring control 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000101/12/11
[43103.360541] usb 1-5: reset high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
```

I figured out it is due to the Logitech webcam in the system (if I disconnect the dmesg flood stops, however, the micro stuttering remains).

Other than that, only these

```
[43210.076621] audit: type=1400 audit(1637700764.751:78): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" name="/proc/sys/kernel/osrelease" pid=1040 comm="cupsd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[43210.076650] audit: type=1400 audit(1637700764.751:79): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" name="/proc/1/environ" pid=1040 comm="cupsd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[43210.076678] audit: type=1400 audit(1637700764.751:80): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" name="/proc/cmdline" pid=1040 comm="cupsd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
```

But I am not sure that it is related. Nothing else.

All packages are the latest. I tried both the latest repo kernel (5.13.0.21.32) and the latest mainline kernel (5.15.4) - it is the same on both.

My hardware:

- Ryzen 5950X
- 64Gb RAM
- MSI X570 Tomahawk
- Radeon RX6700XT

I running the open-source amdgpu driver and Gnome on Wayland with 2x144hz monitors.

Any help is highly appreciated.
Cheers.

Comment: Related: https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/tdqm9q/ubuntu_2004_strange_microstuttering/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue disappeared after I switched back to X11...

```
sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

and uncommented

```
WaylandEnable=false
```

After that

```
sudo service gdm restart
```

login to Ubuntu or Gnome session, and verify that the session is X11 indeed

```
echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE                                                      
x11
```

in my case, I also had to remove the old `xorg.conf`

```
sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.old
```

and just in case I put the following file with `xorg.conf` overrides:

```
cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-amdgpu.conf                                     

Section "Device"
    Identifier "AMD"
    Driver "amdgpu"
    Option "TearFree" "true"
EndSection
```